# Adding a class to a trustedValue AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, directive, 2-way-object-databinding

I have the following html:

```
<li class="editor" ng-model="post.text" ng-bind-html="post.text" add-class="post.text"></li>
```

where post.text is a wrapped trustedValue, that looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ZrcqGHR.png]

after I unwrap it, it looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LJBeArp.png]

Now, I want to make a directive, that searches that trustedValue, and adds a class to the img tags. So far I have this:

```
function AddClassToImg($sce) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            addClass: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var content = scope.addClass.$$unwrapTrustedValue();
            $(content).find('img').addClass('test');
        }
    }
};

angular.module('UserProfile')
    .directive('addClass', ['$sce', AddClassToImg]);
```

How can I get the post.text from the html, two-way-bind to it, and add to all images in post.text that class?

Comment: you can pass post.text just like how you doing addClass in scope

Comment: @V31 I am passing post.text to the scope.. but it doesn't bind, meaning that the class doesn't add when I inspect in chrome..

Comment: You need to inject the compile dependency and re-compile your html after adding the class

Comment: @V31 Seems that I can't get it right, do you have some spare time for some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, for everyone wondering the same thing, here is the code:

```
function AddClassToImg($sce, $compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            addClass: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs){

            var content = scope.addClass.$$unwrapTrustedValue();
            var newContent = $("<div>").append($(content).find('img').addClass('col-md-12 col-xs-12').end()).html();
            scope.addClass = $sce.trustAsHtml(newContent);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just copying your code and adding logic to compile. Their might be slight modifications you might be required to do:

```
function AddClassToImg($sce,$compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            addClass: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var content = scope.addClass.$$unwrapTrustedValue();
            var imgElement = angular.element(content.querySelector('img'));
            imgElement.addClass('test');
            $compile(content)(scope);
        }
    }
};

angular.module('UserProfile')
    .directive('addClass', ['$sce', AddClassToImg]);
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/LA6genC.png . Still doesn't work, as you can see, I called $compile(imgElement) and $compile(content) from console and those where the returns. And at $compile(content) the img doesn't have  the added class